# I have stored uploaded files from amazon s3 to couchdb database. But How to send these response to angularjs to view the files

Tags: node.js, angularjs, couchdb

I have Uploaded files amazon s3 using node js and stored all the information to couchdb. But I didnot able to send these couchdb Json data to angularjs for view the files link

Below My nodejs file

```
app.post('/upload', upload.array('upl',3), function (req, res, next) {
  var data = req.files
  //console.log("doc value",doc )
  console.log("location",data);
  res.send(data);
  var docName = 'rabbit2';
  db.get(docName , function(err, body) {
    if (!err)
      //console.log("cocuhdb body", body._rev);
    var doc = body;
    //console.log("couchdb docname", docName);
    console.log("cocuhdb body", doc);
    //var data = req.files;
    //var docName = doc._id;
    var docName = body._id;
    var docrev = body._rev;
    //console.log("docrev",docrev);
    doc.service.push(data);
    console.log("cocuhdb docName", docName);
    db.insert(doc, docName, docrev, function (error, response) {
      if (!error) {
        res.send(response);
      } else {
        console.log("sad panda",error);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This is my angularjs code

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload">
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="optional title"/>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="file" name="upl" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" ng-click="sub()"/>
  </p>
  <p>{{service[0].location}}</p>
</form>
```

This is angularjs Controller code

```
$scope.sub = function() {
  alert("Hi");
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/upload',
  }).then(
    function(res){
      console.log(res);
    }
  ),
  function(err) {
    console.log('error...', err);
  }
}
```

How to send stored file information from couchdb to angularjs view

Below I attached my database Json file

```
 "fieldname": "upl",
 "originalname": "about3 (1) (1).jpg",
 "encoding": "7bit",
 "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
 "size": 75441,
 "bucket": "gmbdigitalbullleads",
 "key": "about3 (1) (1).jpg",
 "acl": "public-read",
 "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
 "contentDisposition": null,
 "storageClass": "STANDARD",
 "serverSideEncryption": null,
 "metadata": null,
 "location": "https://gmbdigitalbullleads.s3.amazonaws.com/about3%20%281%29%20%281%29.jpg",
 "etag": "\"395ea95843fd0526c008ff9305e62c3c\""
```

Comment: I did not able to get my response in angularjs service.